# Shell scripting get value of XML tags

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xpath

I have the XML data below.

```
<java:Parameter>
       <java:Name>flagCount</java:Name>
       <java:Value>Y</java:Value>
</java:Parameter>
<java:Parameter>
       <java:Name>returnCode</java:Name>
       <java:Value>001</java:Value>
</java:Parameter>
```

I want to get **only Value of Name "returnCode" (Value is 001).**

I try to do by command below, but does't work.

```
echo -e 'cat //java:Value/text()' | xmllint --shell test_check_main.xml

XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
//java:Value/text(): no such node
```

How to implement by shell scripting?

Comment: The XML data seems to be incomplete due to the lack of root node. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797806/namespace-error-namespace-prefix-bd-on-keyword-is-not-defined to refine your question

Comment: Your XML file should define `java` namespace somewhere, with directive like `xmlns:java="(schema_link)"`. Find that out, and add `setns java=(schema_link)` command to your xmllint, this should get rid of error. However, your xpath expression will return both `Y` and `001`, expression for what you want would be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

First fix the xml:

```
xml=$( cat <<'EOF'
<java:Parameter>
   <java:Name>flagCount</java:Name>
   <java:Value>Y</java:Value>
</java:Parameter>
<java:Parameter>
   <java:Name>returnCode</java:Name>
   <java:Value>001</java:Value>
</java:Parameter>
EOF
)
xml2="<java:root xmlns:java=\"http://fakens.com\">""$xml""</java:root>"
```

Then you can get it with this xpath statement:

```
echo "$xml2" | xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="Parameter"]/*[local-name()="Name" and contains(text(),"returnCode")]/parent::*[namespace-uri()="http://fakens.com"]/*[local-name()="Value"]/text()' -
```

It is a bit round-about and annoying, but it is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps you :)

```
cat yourXML.xml | grep -A 1 'returnCode' | tail -1 | grep -oP '(?<=<java:Value>).*' | cut -d '<' -f1
```

There can be multiple ways of doing this but currently i came up with this one.

Comment: [You can't parse XHTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score -1):

another way...

grep returnCode file -A1 | tail -1 |  cut -d\< -f2 | cut -d> -f2